# Converting a line of code to be compatible with storyboards in XCode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard

I have an rss parser that I am converting into a storyboard format, and I ran into an issue. When the user touches a section of the table view that has the rss feed, it pushes the view to a detail view controller with this code:

```
- (id)initWithItem:(NSDictionary *)theItem {
if (self == [super initWithNibName:@"RssDetailController" bundle:nil]) {
    self.item = theItem;
    self.title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
}

return self;
}
```

When I run it, it works fine, but crashes when I try to see the story. Obviously this is because I don't have any nibs anymore because of using storyboards, but how would I change the code to work?

Sorry if my wording is bad. If you have any questions  or need clarification, I will answer then in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to set the property values with a custom init method of your detail view controller, a better way to handle this under the storyboard paradigm would be to do so using the `prepareForSegue:` method of your table view controller.

If you set up a segue in storyboard from your tableview controller to your detail view controller, this method will be called when the segue happens.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{           
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {  // be sure to name your segue in storyboard

        // sender in this case is the tableview cell that was selected
        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;

        // get the index path for the selected cell
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        // use the indexPath to get the appropriate item from your data source
        NSDictionary *theItem = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];  // or whatever

        // get the view controller you are about to segue to
        RssDetailController *rssDetailvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // set the properties
        rssDetailvc.item = theItem;
        rssDetailvc.title = [theItem objectForKey:@"title"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So after I replace the code that i posted with this, what is my next step?

Comment: That should be it.  Points to keep in mind: 1) Make sure you have created a segue in storyboard between your tableview controller and your detail controller (set the segue's Identifier property in the property Inspector to "ShowDetail").  2) The segue will now handle the instantiation of your detail view for you, so you will not need to do anything in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method like you had to do before the arrival of storyboards.

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
 NSDictionary *theItem = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; these two lines are giving me errors

Comment: It says "property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'RSSDetailController *"

Comment: The method `prepareForSegue:` I have given belongs on your tableView controller class, not the detail view controller class.

Comment: Now it doesn't give me any errors, but when I try to touch one of the stories, it doesn't push to the detail view. It doesn't crash though.

Comment: Have you created the segue in your storyboard?  If not, do it like this:  Hold down the Control key while dragging from your tableview's prototype cell to your detail view controller.  When prompted, select 'Push" type Storyboard Segue.  Then click on the newly created segue arrow in your storyboard to select it, and in the Attributes Inspector set the Indentifier value to "ShowDetail".

Comment: Yes I created that. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh one other thing.  Are you using a UINavigationController as the Initial View Controller in your storyboard?  "Push" type segues will only work between view controllers that are being managed by a UINavigationController.

Comment: I have a navigation controller that pushes to the table view, but the table view is just a normal view controller. Ill try making it a nav. controller too.